# Custom user and custom permission on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, user-management

I've this need, I have to install ubuntu on a machine for a specific purpose, and I have to create a particular locked user account.

On startup i need to display the login box (so I have to admin the machine, only reboot and login as root) in the format with username and password fields.

After the login of this user, I have to auto open Google Chrome on a specific page.

Stop, this specific user doesn't have to do more. This machine is connected to a display with show ads in the expo of my client.

How to do this? I don't have any idea. Can anyone tell me ALL the correct step to achieve this?

Thanks in advance, Francesco

Answer (score 1):

Does it HAVE to be Ubuntu? Instead of reinventing the wheel, I'd suggest looking at a distribution aimed at what you're trying to do.

Xibo is one such distro: http://xibo.org.uk/

Comment: First of all, thanks for the reply, it was of big help, but for another project.
However, for this project, it has to be Ubuntu. So how can do this on Ubuntu?